# Do Sirens get any bonus out of Explosive weapons?

Tags: borderlands-2

Sirens get bonus Elemental Effect chance but Explosive weapons appear to ignore "chance" and always deal explosive damage. None of the Siren's skills appear to (directly) effect explosives.

Is there any benefit for Sirens when using Explosive weapons? In Borderlands 1 Sirens' "elemental effect chance" actually improved your "proc pool" which meant you could deal more damaging procs more often, which included Explosive effects. Is that still the case?

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing from [this answer to another question,](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85231/6469) explosive elemental weapons ALWAYS proc. Therefore, any bonuses to elemental effect chance make no difference for explosive weapons.

Comment: I know they always proc, but in BL1 there were different "levels" of procs; x2, x3 and x4. Explosives commonly proc'd but having a bigger tech pool still meant "bigger" procs which did more damage and had a larger visible effect. I'm not sure if that's the case in 2 or not, I haven't noticed varying elemental explosion points like in BL1 (yet)

Comment: Follow-up question here http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/85241/1721