# Which explosive guns can cause critical hits?

Tags: borderlands-2

When I wrote [How do I use elemental effects in Borderlands 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/85230/11920) to the best of my knowledge Explosive guns couldn't critical; I've tested this with "grenade" Assault Rifles, Gyrojet Tourge Assault Rifles and rocket launchers, none of which are able to score a critical (that I ever saw). When using a Tourge explosive Shotgun today, I started getting Criticals just like normal for a shotgun.

Which explosive weapons can cause critical hits? Is there some reason some do and some seem not to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explosive shotguns fire pellets like all the other shotguns. Upon hitting the target, **the pellet applies the explosive element at the point of contact between pellet and enemy.** This means that if the pellet hit a critical part, it cause the explosive damage to be critical.

Grenade assault rifles and rocket launchers won't get critical hits bacause it's firing **a projectile that explodes upon contact with the enemy.** Even if you aim for the weak spot on a huge enemy (crystalisks), it won't apply the critical hit.

Comment: If this is indeed true, you may want to look into editing the explosive section of the answer to [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85230/how-do-i-use-elemental-effects-in-borderlands-2) question

Comment: @Kecoey it seems true from what I've seen

Answer (score 4):

Generally*, in *Borderlands 2*, Torgue explosive weapons have two different firing traits:

- If the weapon spawns with a [barrel component of Torgue manufacture](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Borderlands_2_weapons_by_title), it will shoot **folding fin rockets**. These rockets cause very high damage, but have high spread and low velocity. They also **cannot score critical hits** and each rocket costs multiple units of ammunition. In this case, the explosive damage is included in the damage stated in the weapon card, and calculated by the game as a single hit.
- The other firing trait is present when the [barrel component is from a non-Torgue manufacturer](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Borderlands_2_weapons_by_title). In this case, Torgue weapons will shoot **Gyrojet projectiles**. These projectiles have low initial speed, but accelerate as they travel forwards, and are faster than the folding fin rockets. They also deal additional explosive area-of-effect damage on impact and **can score critical hits**. The game calculates the bullet impact and the explosive effect separately (card only shows projectile damage), and the blast can hit enemies near to the point of impact.

<sup>Source: ["Torgue" Borderlands Wiki article](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Torgue#Usage_.26_Description) (emphasis mine)</sup>

*Note that *the above does not apply to some weapons*:

#### Assault Rifles

The non-Torgue manufactured, Assault Rifles [titled](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Borderlands_2_weapons_by_title): [Cannon](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Cannon) (Manufacturer: Jakobs, Barrel: Torgue) and [Grenadier](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Grenadier_%28assault_rifle%29) (Manufacturer: Dahl, Barrel: Torgue) shoot grenades, instead of folding fin rockets or Gyrojet projectiles. They act like folding fin rockets, in that they also **cannot score critical hits**.

The Seraph Assault Rifle, [Seeker](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Seeker), despite being manufactured by Torgue, and having the barrel not made by Torgue, cannot score critical hits. Weapon special effect description: "*Oh, yeah, that's fair... – Shots fired home in on enemies. Each shot consumes 2 ammo.*"

#### Rocket Launchers

All [Rocket Launchers](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Rocket_Launcher#Borderlands_2) cannot score critical hits, except on a [Crystalisk](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Crystalisk)'s legs.

> <sup>Despite a long-standing belief that the 12 Pounder was the only rocket launcher capable of scoring critical hits on a [Crystalisk](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Crystalisk)'s legs, all rocket launchers are capable of doing so, and none of them are capable of such on other enemies.</sup>

<sup>Source: ["12 Pounder" Borderlands Wiki article](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/12_Pounder)</sup>

#### Unique/Seraph/Legendary weapons

Some notable explosive Unique/Seraph/Legendary weapons that can score critical hits: [Cobra](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Cobra_%28Borderlands_2%29) (Manufacturer: Jakobs; Barrel: Dahl), [Ogre](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Ogre_%28Borderlands_2%29) (Manufacturer: Torgue; Barrel: Vladof), [Unkempt Harold](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Unkempt_Harold) (Manufacturer and Barrel: Torgue).

Some notable explosive Unique/Seraph/Legendary weapons that cannot score critical hits: [KerBlaster](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/KerBlaster) (Manufacturer and Barrel: Torgue),  [Seeker](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Seeker) (Manufacturer: Torgue; Barrel: Vladof).

Answer (score 3):

Every explosive pistol i have used has been able to land criticals. Same for shotguns. Never yet found a rocket launcher or explosive assault rifle that could land a critical.