# How does Close Enough interact with explosive weapons?

Tags: borderlands-2

I know that Gaige can effectively use elemental weapons with Close Enough - the skill that causes up to 50% of your missed shots to ricochet towards the target for reduced damage. However, I do not know what to think of rounds that explode on impact. I noticed that generally elemental weapons leave a small elemental mark on the point of impact and then deal elemental damage normally. What about rockets from RPGs and Torgue weapons? Their projectiles explode on impact and it's really hard to tell (with my limited playtime) if Close Enough has any influence on them.

Would a Torgue projectile explode on impact and then fly towards the enemy to do regular damage? Or would it explode twice? Or maybe explosions prevents ricocheting?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the projectile of the explosive weapon. If the explosive weapon *cannot* score critical hits (e.g. most rocket launchers, and weapons using folding fin rockets or grenades as ammo), it will *not* ricochet towards the target

If the explosive weapon *can* score critical hits (e.g. most explosive weapons using gyrojet projectiles as ammo), it *will* ricochet (even though they appear to explode on impact). More details regarding which explosive weapons can or cannot score critical hits here: [Which explosive guns can cause critical hits?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/118326/4797)

I tested the ff. explosive weapons at the target practice at Marcus' shop:

#### Weapon   —   Ammo Type   —  Can ricochet with Close Enough

Unkempt Harold   -   Gyrojet   -   Yes
KerBlaster   -   Folding fin rockets  -  No
Badaboom   -   Rockets  -   No