# Which weapons deal splash damage?

Tags: borderlands-2

I notice that [Gaige the Mechromancer](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Mechromancer)'s [Close Enough](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Close_Enough) skill doesn't penalize splash damage. So, which are all of the weapons that deal splash damage?

Answer (score 1):

From http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Elemental_Damage:

> All elemental weapons can do splash damage that affects any targets in that area

Additionally damage over time can spread from one enemy to another nearby, e.g. if a bandit gets close to another bandit who's on fire, there's a chance that he'll catch on fire too.

Explosive damage behaves slightly differently as it has an instant area of effect. I don't think other elements on area of effect weapons such as grenades and launchers cause additional splash damage on top of the AoE, but the DoT effects certainly can spread.

Comment: (1) That quote is in the Borderlands (1) section. I doubt that's true for Borderlands 2. (2) I believe DoT is only contagious if the DoT is applied by a weapon whose special effect explicitly causes contagiousness, such as Teapot. Perhaps you mistakenly believe that my question is in regards to Borderlands (1)? (3) I don't believe that contagion = splash damage.

Comment: NiteCyper is right. In Borderlands 2 elemental damage is not dealt in a splash radius, and only spreads due few specific unique weapon effects.

Comment: Im not sure about splash effects with "Close Enough" in general, but there was a question about explosive damage(which is a type of splash damage): [how does close enough interact with explosive weapons?][http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183774/how-does-close-enough-interact-with-explosive-weapons], which states, that gyrojets work with close enough

Answer (score -1):

Splash damage weapons can are usually Torgue-manufactured weapons:

> In Borderlands 2, explosive damage is largely exclusive to Torgue-manufactured products. However, several other manufacturers feature weapons that deal explosive damage in some manner. They include:
>
> - Assault Rifles that use Torgue barrels (Bandit, Dahl, Jakobs, and Vladof)
> - Rocket Launchers (Bandit, Tediore, and Vladof)
> - Cobra sniper rifle
> - Tediore non-elemental weapons (when reload-thrown)
> - Bouncing Bonny, Bouncing Betty, Jumpin Bitty, and Jumpin Biddy grenades
> - Grenades and Gurnades
> - Murrv, Mrvur, and Muvr grenades
> - Kiss of Death grenade
> - Singularity Grenades
> - Transfusion Grenades
> - The Cradle shield (when depleted and discarded)

Source: http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Elemental_Damage#Explosive_Damage_Exclusivity

Comment: Your quote contradicts your answer. "can only be Torgue"..."largely exclusive to Torgue.. others include.."