# How do I deal more DPS?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have been playing a few games co-op with teammates, and I have noticed that against (literally) all of them, I seem to be dealing the least DPS... even when they are a much lower level than me.

Is there any way or some tips to deal more DPS?

**Edit:** They are a much lower level than me, but it might be the guns I am using. Even though I am using SMGs of my level, I deal less DPS. Should I consider switching to assault rifles?

Comment: find better guns?

Comment: Are you the same level? Do they deal more damage with the same guns? It's hard to tell what your specific problem is since there's a great deal of reasons you might be dealing less damage

Comment: What was your Basass Rank compared to your teammates'? Maybe they focused their Badass points for offense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest way to increase your damage done is to aim for the critical location on enemies. You will increase your damage output immensely by constantly hitting those spots.

Of course this also requires you to learn where those critical locations are. This would be a very large list for every specific enemy in the game.

For most targets, the head is a safe bet as the critical hit location. Exceptions are spiderants where their exposed tail, varkids have a small eye like area on their rear section as well, and all robot types (they have 2, the lighted "eye" is almost always a spot and some you can shot off their limb joints as well. The joints aren't always a spot as some robots are designed differently than others.

If you are playing Zero, the assassin, you can invest into B0re skill. With it, every time you use his special ability, the critical hit locations of the enemies will be highlighted with a red hexagon.

Also consider your class talent choices. Each class has talents that increase damage done by a generic or specific gun type. Those talents will further increase your damage done to targets.

Make sure you keep upgrading your guns as well (replacing older guns with new, more powerful ones). The base damage they do directly impacts how much damage output you have. Elemental Effects play a huge part as well. [Please make sure you read this entire answer.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85230/how-do-i-use-elemental-effects-in-borderlands-2)

Different weapons also have different multipliers for these critical hits as found on a table listed [here.](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Critical_hit_%28Borderlands_2%29)
The list below is listed as Weapon Type -> Critical Damage Bonus

- Assault Rifles -> +66%
- Launchers -> no criticals
- Pistols -> +100%
- Shotguns -> +100%
- Sniper Rifles -> +300%
- Sub-Machine guns -> +100%

Jakobs weapons are special:

- Assault Rifles -> +130%
- Pistols -> +150%
- Shotguns -> +130%
- Sniper Rifles -> +420%!

Comment: How do you 'upgrade your guns'?

Comment: @Meraj99 By "upgrading" he means being not afraid to swap them for better ones. There is no mechanism to improve existing guns in BL2. I've made edits to the answer, be sure to wait until they are reviewed.

Comment: Sorean Said it pretty well, focus on criticals, use the right elemental for the right target (fire on flesh, shock on shields, caustic on armored/robots {anything with a yellow health bar}, slag against anything that is not already slagged) and just because something is purple or orange does not mean it is the best for you especially if it is 5 or more levels below you.  A lv 35 siren with a random green lv 35 maliwan fire SMG might do much more than that same siren with a lv 27 hellfire SMG.