# How to solo Pyrocaustic Pete the Invincible?

Tags: borderlands-2

Is he possible to beat solo? Getting through his shield is the easy part but how would you damage his actual health?

He is resistant to both fire and corrosive so those are out of the question. I don't see how he can be beaten.

Comment: Shock does 1.0x damage against health in BL2: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85231/11920 and he's only resistant to Corrosive while using corrosive attacks

Comment: When you take his shield down though he uses fire and corrosive so isn't he resistant to both then?

Comment: Not sure, he seemed to take more damage from Corrosive than Fire, but I avoided both and went for shock/nonelemental

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Various tips:

- [Shock does normal damage against flesh/armor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85230/how-do-i-use-elemental-effects-in-borderlands-2/85231#85231), so 1.0x not 0.8x. Shock works just fine against him and makes removing the shield a breeze. Non-elemental works fine against him too I think.
- **The Bee** really really helps, especially during the start. Aside from the Damage over Time effects, it's extremely easy to dodge Pete's attack if you simply walk backwards and shoot at him.
- Pete can be **slagged** like a normal enemy for a normal duration. If you have Slag grenades or a skill that slags, use it. Slag guns are far less useful in solo play through.
- His DOT (damage over time) effects never wear off over time, so don't wait for them to go away.
- The water valves open and let you remove the long lasting DOT effects from his novas. walk through the water to remove the DOT effect. The DOT effect is weak but it limits your shield's abilities (read: it removes The Bee's effect)
- Opening the valves spawns a group of Rats or Spiderants. They increase in level by 3 each time they're spawned, ending in 66 I think.
- Consider letting two DOT effects stack before opening the valves. This will limit the leveling up of the mobs from the valves
- Open the south (I think) valve as it has **Spiderants**. The spiderants are far far easier to deal with than the Rats
- If one spiderant/rat is alive when you turn the valve, no more will spawn. If you can stand leaving a spiderant alive and kite him around like Pete you should be able to water yourself down immediately after each nova no problem.
- There are respawning ammo crates around the arena for a reason. Try and open them every once in a while for health/ammo since he takes a LOT of bullets to kill.
- Some people suggest Fire/Corrosion immunity shields to limit his DOT effect, but later on in the fight he'll be doing both Fire and Corrode DOT every Nova anyway, so unless you've got a fire/corrode immune Bee I wouldn't bother with it trying to immunize yourself.
- Immunity doesn't mean you don't take the DOT damage either, it just significantly reduces it. So you'll still slowly lose health and never have full shields.

In short, use Shock or normal damage, slag him, use the Bee, release Spiderants not rats. Try to always leave a spiderant around to kill for a second wind (and so you can open the valve without washing in more enemies each time). The fight is mostly about managing the non-pete enemies to make sure you can wash off the DOT, can get a second wind but so you don't get swarmed. Pyro Pete isn't actually a big problem except for the loooong fight and the DOT effects, just keep moving and he'll never hit you with anything else. No shields spawn with immunity to both elements (unless there's a unique/legendary I'm unfamiliar with)

He can be soloed, but of course a group really does help. With a group it's much easier to manage the spiderants/rats, he's less focused on one target and it's much easier to open the valves since you can assign one person to always do that.

Here's a video demo of a Siren soloing him:

Comment: What about his AoE things that hit you no matter what?

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk what about them? Those are only to cause the DOT which I covered extensively. There's no avoiding them or anything.

Comment: Didn't notice the "from his novas part the first time I read it, you're right.

Comment: Wiki article suggests using two shields with elemental resistance *when soloing*, because it is possible to insta-swap them between fire and corrosive novas.

Comment: @OrcJMR ohhh hadn't thought of that actually! I'm so used to opening the menu being a death-sentance in multiplayer. Do immunity shields remove current DOT effects too then?

Comment: No idea, honestly, but I'd not count on that much...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to grenade jump (unequip grenade mod, throw, be in air nearby when it explodes) up onto one of the ledges beside a column, and then up to a couple of huts, I think to the left of where you enter (definitely not the hut with the dook hut).

It makes taking cover from the novas very easy, you can pop in/out of cover, and if he is on the other side of a hut you won't take damage from them even if you're 10 metres away.

If you're not using a Gunzerker/Hoarder mod combo, ammo might get a bit tight.  In this case, take at least one of every weapon type with you, make sure you're getting the best damage/ammo you can out of each, and make sure your skill tree is damage-focused (Kunai/Cataclysm for Assassin/Siren).  Cooldown relic/mods will help here.

Answer (score 0):

I was Level 42 when I did it solo and it was my first Borderlands Raid ever. Took me one try with Zer0. I used a Jakobs Revolver w/ 4300 Damage, Torgue Rocket Launcher w/ 36,966 Dam, Valdof Slag TMP and Corrosive LMG when his shield was gone, and had the Magic Missle Slag Grenades 8877x2 Damage and they Regen themselves. Class Mod: Disturbed Stalker +23% Pistol Fire Rate, +29% Mag Size, +26% Shield Recharge Rate with +3 Rising Shot. Vitality Relic +38% Health. Armored Turtle Shield 10,286 Cap, 827 Recharge Rate, 5.04 Second Delay, and -2115 Health. What I did was slag him, go in Deception, and shoot him with a rocket to do 42K Damage until I ran out of Rockets. I used the Grenades a lot and the Jakobs Revolver to do a lot of DPS. And just ran in circles in the area to avoid his attacks and to activate the Digistruct Ammo Supplys. When he uses his Ultimate Attack Dont use the Pipe that sends down the Rat except use the Spierant one. They are easier to dodge and take down quicker. Just got to play smart and outlast him, don't give up even if it seems like it's taking a while. Took me around 30 Minutes for me. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Pryo Pete is such a fun fight. One easy way to fight him is using either the alkine the bee or inflammable the bee (or both during his pyrocaustic stage) and a shock sandhawk from Captain Scarletts Campaign. During his nova attacks in the second stage, when you inventory on solo it pauses the game. so after the first initial nova wave whether it is fire or corrosive,you switch to the other shield to protect from the wave and counteract the DoT from his attack, hereby negating the use of water falls so you will never need to spawn the spiderants or rats. The main strategy is kite him in circles shooting him with the sandhawk then switch to another gun if you need ammo, however if you have maxed out your smg ammo capacity with eridium from the black market, you should be good if you can land critical shots on his head or flame pack. Using the magic missle helps with extra damage due to slag, and if you are playing siren, specing into the cataclysm tree with the abilities to cause slag, shock, fire, and corrosive damage from the phaselock. If you want to land critical headshots easily, use the tresspasser sniper rifle given as a reward from Mordecai. It has the special effect to bypass shields which can allow you to remove pyro petes helmet in his shield stage and land more critical hits dealing massive damage.