# How to solo Hyperius?

Tags: borderlands-2

As per [my other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102135/how-to-solo-pyrocaustic-pete-the-invincible), I successfully found how to solo Pyro Pete. Hyperius however, seems so much more difficult.

What is the most effective way to kill him? Should I go after the bots first then focus on him? Though once Hyperius loses *his* shield, he does a nova to take down mine. Since I'm using The Bee shield, this severely drops my damage output.

Also, are there elements I should avoid or try to use? For example, Will he take more damage from shock weapons because of that 'shield' he has around him, or more damage from fire because his health bar is red, meaning flesh?

Comment: Are you attempting to get achievements for beating Hyperious?

Comment: @aviangentile Are there achievements for it, Or do you mean badass challenge? Either way I just want to beat him and get to Master Gee. Also, Seraph Crystals.

Comment: There is an achievement for finishing all Captain Scarlett side missions, which includes beating Hyperious and Master Gee. Basically I ask because if you're not doing it for challenge or high level loot, you can fight him on Normal Mode. The game was patched in the last month to cap Hyperious and Master Gee at (I think) level 32 on Normal Mode, which makes fighting them EXTREMELY easy if you're already at level 50.

Comment: Well it's a shame I don't have internet or I'd update it then. Though I think I also don't have the Bee shield+shotguns nerf either. Can't remember last time I updated.

Comment: That was nerfed in the same update as the cap on Hyperious and Master Gee if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: What class are you using?

Comment: Not sure if that's good or bad for me then, hmm. I just figure if I can beat Terramorphous and Pyro Pete, then I should be able to kill Hyperius too. I'm using the assassin. I switch my build around too often to really say what it is though.

Comment: Note that they don't drop seraph crystals on normal mode anymore due to the dropped level cap on Normal for them. Kinda hard to answer this with you on a version most people no longer run though...

Comment: @Ben I just updated yesterday. Was dissapointed when I didn't get the crystals :(

Comment: Evil Masher is now the way to go.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk Updated your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest trick to solo Hyperius is to use the Evil Masher Glitch/Exploit.  It hasn't been patched yet, but it's been around a long time.  Basically, the Evil Masher is an assault rifle with sub-par stats, a reward from Marcus's mission (Kai).

When reloading however, there is a chance to "power up" the weapon. Taken from the BL Wikia:

> There are at least six possible outcomes to Evil Smasher reloading:
>
> - Power up level 1, indicated by the power-up sound and explosion. Slight increase in power and reduced recoil for bullets in the next
>     clip. No change in clip size.
> - Power up level 2, indicated by a louder power-up sound cue, and explosion larger than that of level 1. All round improved weapon stats
>     compared with level 1. In particular next clip increases in size to
>     about 30.
> - Power up level 3, louder cues than level 2, high stats than level 2, in particular clip size increases to about 50.
> - Power up level 4, the previous trend continues. All round improvement to level 3, in particular clip size increases to about 70.
> - Power up level 5, similar as before but bigger and better. In particular clip size increases to about 90.
> - Nothing. No sound or explosion. Weapon returns to base stats for the next clip.

As for the glitch:

> As soon as the power-up sound and visual cue occur on Evil Smasher,
>   and if player swap Evil Smasher right away, the power-up effects of
>   Evil Smasher will now apply to the newly swapped weapon, and stacks on
>   top of the weapon's other properties. ALL weapons in active slots now
>   inherit ALL of Evil Smasher's special property of powering up (i.e.
>   chance to power-up after reload, with same explosion and power-up
>   sound).
>
> Take this example. Say when reloading Evil Smasher, the cues indicate
>   the next clip with be at the highest power-up level. If the player
>   switches immediately to, say, Infinity, before Evil Smasher finishes
>   reloading, Infinity now has increased clip size, improved damage, fire
>   rate and recoil reduction proportional to Evil Smasher highest
>   power-up level. Even though the normal Infinity property of having
>   clip size of 1 is "overwritten" by Evil Smasher power-up, Infinity's
>   other original properties (never using ammo and bullet spread looks
>   like infinity symbol) remain.
>
> When combined with the Infinity repeater pistol in the stated manner
>   and The Bee, and due to the dramatical increase to fire rate, the
>   player can kill any of the Invincible foes in a matter of seconds
>   (usually less than five seconds, even on True Vault Hunter Mode). For
>   example, Voracidous the Invincible can be killed before Chief Ngwatu
>   spawns, and Hyperius the Invincible even before his loader minions
>   have time to make it invulnerable. This exploit has, as such, game
>   breaking effects. Also, when using this glitch with Voracidous, he
>   will instantly respawn after going outside of the fightning area,
>   without the need to pay Eridium again or rezone.
>
> This power-up effect applies to all weapons in active slots until the
>   current game session ends, or switching back to Evil Smasher. It does
>   not go away even after respawn, fast travel or entering inventory
>   menu. In multiplayer session, the clip count may reset to base stat
>   after fast travel, still all Evil Smasher properties remain.
>
> This glitch is most noticeable for weapons with low clip count, such
>   as Rocket Launcher and Sniper Rifle. Rocket Launcher under this glitch
>   can easily have clip size above 27, more than the maximum a normal
>   backpack can hold

Comment: Does that still work after the massive Tediore reload/amp shield nerf? This video was before the nerf I believe. Amp damage used to apply to every single bullet for the reload, now it applies once. That has the potential to cut the damage in this video by ~40k*52 per reload

Comment: No, this does not work since the Bee nerf. Even full-clip Tediore throws do just a little more damage than a single bullet with The Bee.

Comment: Do I have to go through the power up levels (1-2-3-4-5) or can I reload and go straight to any of those?

Comment: It's a random roll, so you could be REALLY lucky and hit power level 5, but most of thee time you won't get from 1 to 5 that fast

Comment: Basically, if you're on level 0 (no bonus), your chance to hit level 5 on the first reload is a lot less likely than getting to level 1.  If you're on power level 3, then your chance to get to level 5 is higher, than going down to level 2, or level 1.

Answer (score 0):

I personally when fighting him alone went for his robots first and then targeted him he has a shield that makes it so I think you have to do it that way. I used corrosive rocket launchers and a turtle shield and managed to kill him by myself